# Multiline user input python

Tags: python, input

I would like to know how to write a simple program that can accept multiple lines of input, then the input can be submitted like in the lynx browser, where you use a blank line and then a period to submit the input.

i want to use it in an email program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python

Comment: This question is a little different, i am asking how to submit the input.

Comment: Ah, so you already know how to get the multiline input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input_list = []

while True:
    input_str = raw_input(">")
    if input_str == "." and input_list[-1] == "":
        break
    else:
        input_list.append(input_str)

for line in input_list:
    print line
```

Comment: You can also add input_list.pop() before the break if you don't want to include the final blank line in your input.

Comment: @kylek Click the tick under his vote count on the left :). However, I think you have to wait a certain amount of minutes

Comment: There should be a checkmark symbol to the left of my answer, when you ask a question, you're supposed to click that for the answer which best answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that feature also.