# python emailing one line at a time

Tags: python, email

My email program is emailing each line of the message as a separate email, i would like to know how to send all of the message in one email, when the email is sent the program will return to the beginning.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

a = 1
while a == 1:
    print " "
    To = raw_input("To: ")
    subject = raw_input("subject: ")
    input_list = []
    print "message: "
    while True:
        input_str = raw_input(">")
        if input_str == "." and input_list[-1] == "":
            break
        else:
            input_list.append(input_str)

    for line in input_list:

        # Create a MIME text message and populate its values
        msg = MIMEText(line)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = '123@example.com'
        msg['To'] = To

        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('server', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login('username', 'password')

        # Send a properly formatted MIME message, rather than a raw string
        server.sendmail('user@example.net', To, msg.as_string())
        server.close()
```

(the part that takes multiple lines was made with the help Paul Griffiths,  [Multiline user input python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016240/multiline-user-input-python))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for line in input_list:

        # Create a MIME text message and populate its values
        msg = MIMEText(line)
```

You are calling `server.sendmail` in this loop.

Build your entire msg first (in a loop), THEN add all of your headers and send your message.