# Is there a way to implement a multiline string input for the code in python below?

Tags: python, input, multiline

There is a translation table (dictionary) above this code.

Synopsis of the code:

Converting/translating a string of characters to another character in a different ASCII/Unicode-8 character and printing this output to a new file with a user inputted name.

The input of this conversion should be a user input and should accept multiline string.

```
print("Enter PC2 text to convert to InPage: ")

text = sys.stdin.read()
translated = text.maketrans(translation)
finaltext = text.translate(translated)

print("Provide a name of the file:")
fileofname = input()
name = fileofname+'.txt'

with open(name, 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    f.write(finaltext)
```

I have tried the following ways to overcome this issue and none of them have worked out the way I intent it to:

1. import sys
2. while looping
3. raw_input (python 2)
4. EOF

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` will keep reading until you type the EOF character (Ctl-d on Unix). So that will accept multiline input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline user input python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016240/multiline-user-input-python)

Comment: Prompted with a EOFErorr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\PC2 to InPage.py", line 48, in <module>
    fileofname = input()
                 ^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: `text = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines())` should work, using ctrl-D or ctrl-Z to finish

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

// print("Enter PC2 text to convert to InPage:")
// text = input()

lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    lines.append(line)

text = ''.join(lines)

translated = text.maketrans(translation)
finaltext = text.translate(translated)

print("Provide a name for the file:")
fileofname = input()
name = fileofname+'.txt'

with open(name, 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    f.write(finaltext)
```

please note, in python 3, you should use input() instead of `raw_input()` for user input

Comment: How would I end the input?

Comment: you can use the Ctrl + D key combination on Unix-based systems (including macOS and Linux) or Ctrl + Z on Windows systems @BotZakk

Comment: I am getting EOF error: EOF when reading a line

Comment: I ran the exe of this and used the EOF combination to end the input but the file created is empty and does not contain the expected output.

Comment: you can use  (""" or ''') for multiline string , for example """
This is a
multiline
string input.
""" @BotZakk

Comment: Prematurely exits the terminal as soon as the input is pasted and no new file is created.

Comment: Originally, the code used (''') but now since I am converting it to an exe, I need it to be a user input.

Comment: It sounds like the program is exiting before you have a chance to provide any input, the  possible explanation is that the program is running into an error and crashing

Comment: No, because I have to paste in the input, I am not manually giving in the multiline input, its a CTRL + V command.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop on a regular `input()` in an infinite loop that you let the user break with ctrl-C:

```
text = ""
while True:
    try:   text += input() + "\n"
    except KeyboardInterrupt: break
```

Comment: This won't work because the entire input will be pasted and it'll already be multiline.