# Input a multiline string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to create a simple programme that inputs a single multiline input and outputs it as a table.

input:

```
a
b
c
```

I know i could have done this is easily in python 2.7.5 by using:

```
input_string = raw_input("> ").splitlines()
```

this would return ['a', 'b', 'c']

however in python 3, the line:

```
input_string = input("> ").splitlines()
```

only returns `['a']` hence it only reads the first line of the input string.

Is there any way in python 3 to accept a multiline input? Thanks.

Comment: I believe this to be related.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python

Comment: it is pointless to call `.splitlines()` on the output of `raw_input()` that reads at most one line.

Comment: This not duplicate question at all. This is related to python 2 not python 3, as question says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try.

```
aux = ''
'\n'.join(iter(input, aux))
```

Comment: @DSM oh yes, I forgot it, I changed it to `input`, thx.