# How does raw_input treat ENTER or \n

Tags: python, input

I have a long list of numbers that I would like to input into my code through a raw_input. It includes numbers that are spaced out through `SPACES` and `ENTER/RETURN`. The list looks like [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) . When I try to use the function raw_input, and copy paste the long list of numbers, my variable only retains the first row of numbers. This is my code so far:

```
def main(*arg):
    for i in arg:
        print arg

if __name__ == "__main__": main(raw_input("The large array of numbers"))
```

How can I make my code continue to read the rest of the numbers?
Or if that's not possible, can I make my code acknowledge the ENTER in any way?

P.s. While this is a project euler problem I don't want code that answers the project euler question, or a suggestion to hard code the numbers in. Just suggestions for inputting the numbers into my code.

Comment: Why would you try to input the list via raw_input? I don't believe that is how you should go about doing this

Comment: Imagine that raw_input did read newlines - how would it know when to stop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raw input across multiple lines in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)

Comment: I've deleted my answer in favor of the better answer on that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are actually looking for is to directly read from `stdin`  via `sys.stdin`. But you need to accept the fact that there should be a mechanism to stop accepting any data from `stdin`, which in this case is feasible by passing an `EOF` character. An `EOF` character is passed via the key combination `[CNTRL]+d`

```
>>> data=''.join(sys.stdin)
Hello
World
as
a
single stream
>>> print data
Hello
World
as
a
single stream
```

Comment: could you explain this a little more? I have never heard of stdin or the .join you put in front of it.

Comment: @RonaldRojas: I though it was pretty straight forward. The standard input stdin is a file like iterable object for standard input. The ''.join, is the string join method which consumes the standard input until EOF is reached. EOF is reached when user deliberately enters [CNTRL]+d

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this code should work (assuming it's in python 2.7):

```
sentinel = '' # ends when this string is seen
rawinputtext = ''
for line in iter(raw_input, sentinel):
    rawinputtext += line + '\n' #or delete \n if you want it all in a single line
print rawinputtext
```

(code taken from: [Raw input across multiple lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python) )

PS: or even better, you can do the same in just one line!

```
rawinputtext = '\n'.join(iter(raw_input, '') #replace '\n' for '' if you want the input in one single line
```

(code taken from: [Input a multiline string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750323/input-a-multiline-string-in-python?lq=1) )