# Unsure how to get user input from a multiple line loop - Python

Tags: python, loops, input

I have been trying to create a program that lets users name, write and save documents, here is what I have come up with so far:

```
doc_name = str(input("Document Name: "))
end = ""
for line in iter(input, end):
    document = "\n".join(iter(input, end))
    pass
try:
    savefile = open("/home/" +doc_name+ ".txt", "w")
    savefile.write(x)
    savefile.close()
    print("Document - " +doc_name+ "\nSuccessfully saved.\n\n")
except:
    print("An error occurred.\nUnable to save document.\n\n")
```

The 'for loop' I have used was from the following page:
[Raw input across multiple lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python) but I am unsure how to use the input from this loop, so I am able to save it to a textfile.
I need the input in this line of code in the place of x:

```
savefile.write(x)
```

I am using Python 3.2.3 for this program (if that helps?).
I would like to know how the user input entered during the for loop can be stored in a varible and then used at some other point in the program.

Thanks.

Comment: The idention of your code is not valid Python. Please fix it.

Comment: @Tichodroma sorry about that, must have had some problems when copying the code over. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: What is `for line in iter(input, end):` supposed to mean? `input` is a Python builtin function.

Comment: @Tichodroma I have substituted the `raw_input` from this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python for `input` instead. Although, this might not be correct, because I am a beginner when it comes to Python.

Comment: i tried the code (after deleting iters) with my python 3.2. albeit it spits error, it actually saves file.

Comment: @marmeladze did it let you input before giving an error? When I removed the `iter`s, it wouldn't let me input and didn't save the file either. For this code: `document = "\n".join(input, end)`, I got this error: `TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` and when putting another set of brackets over `((input, end))`, it gave the error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, builtin_function_or_method found`.

Comment: here is the code, i've tried http://ur1.ca/ka7yq

Comment: @marmeladze thanks for trying that out, but I'm not sure what the random numbers are for? Also, that program doesn't let the user input on more than one line.

Comment: i just put it, for files not being empty :) not anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc_name = input("Document Name: ") # don't need to cast to str
end = ""
result = [] # I recommend initializing a list for the lines
for line in iter(input, end): # you only need this single input call
    result.append(line) # add each line to the list
try:
    # using "with" in this manner is guaranteed to close the file at the end
    with open("/home/" +doc_name+ ".txt", "w") as savefile:
        for line in result: # go through the list of lines
            # write each one, ending with a newline character
            savefile.write(line + '\n')
except IOError:
    print("An error occurred.\nUnable to save document.\n\n")
else: # print this if save succeeded, but it's not something we want to "try"
    print("Document - " +doc_name+ "\nSuccessfully saved.\n\n")
```

You only need to use `pass` when Python expects statements (such as in an indented block) but you have no statements for it to execute - it's basically a placeholder. The common use is when you want to define your program's functions (e.g., `def myfunction(a, b):`) but you don't have the actual content for them yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed info, but I've just run the program and instead of writing each line to the textfile, it has written each character on another line. Do you think there is any way to avoid this?

Comment: I forgot it was a `list`. I've edited the code to use `append()` instead.