# Python split by newline

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, newline

I am having trouble splitting a string of characters into a list by the newline. My code:

```
i=raw_input().split("\n")
```

Does `.split()` do what I think it does? And if so, how do I get it to co-operate?

Here's my input as well:

```
>>>>>>v
^     v
^     >>>>X
```

Answer (score 5):

As given in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

> **raw_input([prompt])**
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. **The function then reads a line from input**, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

It reads a single line from the input. If you want to read three lines from the input, you have to use three `raw_input()` , you can read the three `raw_input()` and append them to list . Example -

```
lst = [raw_input(), raw_input(), raw_input()]
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = [raw_input(), raw_input(), raw_input()]
1
2
3
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

---

If you are redirecting standard input from a file or somewhere else, As mentioned in the comments by @KevinGuan , you can also use `sys.stdin.read()` to read the complete input at once and then do split on that. Example -

```
import sys
x = sys.stdin.read()
print(x.split('\n'))
```

A sample text file -

```
Blah
Blah1
blah2
```

Result -

```
python a.py < a.txt
['Blah', 'Blah1', 'blah2']
```

But please note, if you are redirecting from a file, I would rather use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) to read the file in python itself.

Comment: Yea possible, I have added that to my answer, but if its being redirected from a file, I would rather use `open()` .

Comment: Well, so is my new answer useless?

Comment: No, you can keep it. I have upvoted it, its a good answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you would like to use `sys.stdin.read()`:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
data_list = data.strip().split('\n')

print data_list
```

**output:**

```
# here is the input:
>>>>>>v
^     v
^     >>>>X

# then press Ctrl+D on Linux, or Ctrl+Z on Windows
['>>>>>>v', '^     v', '^     >>>>X']
```

Comment: This would be a perfect answer for [*How do I read multiple lines of raw input in Python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11664443/3357935)

Answer (score 0):

To read lines from a file into a Python **list** using your example input:

```
import fileinput

lines = [line.strip() for line in fileinput.input('input.txt')]
```

The output:

```
>>> lines
['>>>>>>v', '^     v', '^     >>>>X']
```