# How to input an unknown size of strings with newlines in Python?

Tags: python

I need input data from keyboard in console Python like this:

```
 1427  0   

   876652098643267843 
5276538
```

How can I catch them to array?

Comment: can you please explain the input? Are the input values space separated or are they in newlines?

Comment: In one line can be any size of numbers and between numbers can be any size of spaces. Also I can input any size of empty lines between lines

Comment: how is the input terminated?

Comment: in C++ terminated by EOF command. in Python i can't find(((

Comment: the task is http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001&locale=en

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing any code?

Comment: Do you really want to allow blank lines and terminate only on an actual EOF signal?

Comment: I attempted to split into array

Comment: Yeah - the task allowed blank lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to send EOF and have the script process the data, you can use this code:

```
import math
import sys
result = []
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    data = line.split(' ')
    for Ai in data:
        Ai = Ai.strip()
        try:
            result.append(math.sqrt(int(Ai)))
        except:
            pass

for i in reversed(result):
    print("%.4f"%i)
```

On Windows you need to press CRTL + Z and then ENTER. You will see ^Z in the CMD shell.
On Linux press CTRL + D.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    #your code
    print(line)
```

This will accept a stream of characters till EOF is encountered. (Cnrl + D)

You may then split the each line to obtain individual values.

Comment: I think the OP was referring to EOF because that's how it's done in C++ and it's the only way he knows of.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the multiline data in Python. How to to this is described here: [raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)

Once you have your input in a variable you process it.

Very simple example. Don't know if it meets the requirements from your task:

```
import math
sentinel = '#' 
result = []
all_data = iter(raw_input, sentinel)
for line in all_data:
    data = line.split(' ')
    for Ai in data:
        Ai = Ai.strip()
        try:
            result.append(math.sqrt(int(Ai)))
        except:
            pass

for i in reversed(result):
    print("%.4f"%i)
```

Now your task is to optimize.

Comment: Thank you too. this part of code will help me in future tasks)

Comment: Have you noticed the accept answer button and "This answer is useful"  buttons? :)

Comment: Oo i have only 9 reputation. wait untill i will be 15))