# Read multiple inputs from multiple line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

Input:
691 41
947 779

Output:
1300
336

I have tried this solution [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)

but my problem is end of **last line** is unknown

My Code:

```
for line in iter(input,"\n"):                                                               
    a,b = line.split()
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    result = 2 * (a - b)
    print(result)
```

My code is printing the desired output but the for loop is not terminating. I am a new bee to python is there any way to find the last input from the stdin console???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you missing is that `input()` strips the newline from the end of the string it returns, so that when you hit `<RET>` all alone on a line what `iter()` sees (i.e., what it tests to eventually terminate the loop) is not `"\n"` but rather the empty string `""` (NB definitely **no spaces** between the double quotes).

Here I cut&paste an example session that shows you how to define the correct sentinel string (the null string)

```
In [7]: for line in iter(input, ""):
   ...:     print(line)
   ...:     
asde
asde


In [8]:
```

As you can see, when I press `<RET>` all alone on a n input line, the loop is terminated.

ps: I have seen that [gcx11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3450318/gcx11) has posted [an equivalent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42481107/2749397) (that I've upvoted). I hope that my answer adds a bit of context and shows how it's effectively the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Function input is stripping trailing \n, so just use empty string as delimiter in function iter.

Comment: i have tried with empty string as delimiter but in that case also for loop is not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned that you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)
But it seems that you implement a `'\n'` as `sentinel` (to use a term from the post from the link).

You may need to try to actually use a stop word, something like this:

```
stopword = 'stop'
for line in iter(input, stopword):                                                               
    a,b = line.split()
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    result = 2 * (a - b)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are using **stop** as stopword ?? in my case i dont know when the input will terminate.

Comment: You need somehow break the for-loop. In this example the "input" "stop\n" will break the loop.

Comment: Plz tell me what can i use as stopword for my input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you need, but I didn't figure out where your inputs comes from, I tried to adapt your code by reading everything from `std in` using `fileinput` and leaving when "Enter" is pressed:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if line == '\n':
        break
    a, b = line.split()
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    result = 2 * (a - b)
    print(result)
```

Comment: I didn't know the built-in function `input`. My sricpt works if you use it outside of the python `console` otherwise @gboffi answers is probably what you are looking for.