# Python code for single line list input as well as multiple line array input

Tags: python

Do we have any through which we can take single line as well as multi- line list input in Python?
Like in C++ we have :-

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  cin>>A[i]; //this will take single line as well as multi-line input .
}
```

Now in Python we have :-

```
l=list(map(int,input().strip().split())) //for single line 
           &
l=list()
for i in range of(0,5):
      x=int(input())
      l.append(x) //for multi-line input
```

So my Question is do we have any python code which can take single as well as multi line input just the we we have in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raw input across multiple lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)

Comment: I'd say slightly different use cases. The minimal example he provides (as opposed to none) is also superior IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-inventing the square wheel is easy:

```
def m_input(N):
    if(N < 1): return []
    x = input().strip().split()[:N]
    return x + m_input(N - len(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) reads a single line.

Minimal example with multi-line 'input'.

```py
>>> lines = sys.stdin.readlines() # Read until EOF (End Of 'File'), Ctrl-D
1 # Input
2 # Input
3 # Input. EOF with `Ctrl-D`.
>>> lines # Array of string input
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
>>> map(int, lines) # "functional programming" primitive that applies `int` to each element of the `lines` array. Same concept as a for-loop or list comprehension. 
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you're uncomfortable using `map`, consider a list compression:

```py
>>> [int(l) for l in lines]
[1, 2, 3]
```