# how can i add a new line using x.write(input()) in python

Tags: python, file, input

```
     with open('practice.txt','w') as x:
          text = input('enter text')
          x.write(text)
```

enter text .. hello\n world

output .. hello\n world

it takes it as a string not as a newline character
why is my input string when passed to a write() not validating my'\n' character

Does it have something to do with me passing input() to write()

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input-in-python

Comment: `\n` is only used to *represent* a newline. Those two characters don't have any special meaning here because `input()` doesn't parse escape sequences. You'll have to figure out a way to do that yourself (e.g. `text = text.replace('\\n', '\n')`).

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a raw string so all newlines are automatically escaped. You can convert this back into a literal string with `literal_eval()` from `ast`.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('practice.txt','w') as x:
      text = input('enter text')
      x.write(literal_eval("'" + text + "'"))
```

For example:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = input()
>>>"\tHello!"
print(a)
>>>\tHello!
print(literal_eval("'" + a + "'"))
>>>    Hello!
```

Comment: This will break if you use a single quote anywhere in the text, though. You could use triple quotes (`"'''" + a + "'''"`), but that also breaks for some inputs.

Comment: You're right. I can't think of a way to convert it without breaking for at least one type of character. Is there actually no perfect way to convert from raw to literal?

Comment: For some reason there isn't a nice way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Okay that's a definite improvement. It still can't decode if there is a '\' at the end though

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a multiline input from the user, so that you wouldn't need to type the control character.

See here: [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)