# Multiple inputs from a user in a single line for pythong

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-input

With python you have input()
it takes one user input and you can assign it to a variable and then do what you please.
I have heard about the .split() method but don't know how to implement it into my code.
I want to create a function use def() so i can call back the function several times while asking the user for input as to whether they want to got through with the process, end it or do another function

```
print("Hello, welcome to the change calculator")
print("Here we will ask you to tell us the amount of each individual coins you have")
#create variables that hold the amount each one states such as five pence would == £0.05
fivepence = 0.05
tenpence = 0.10
twentypence = 0.20
fiftypence = 0.50
onepound = 1
twopound = 2
#Get the user to input everything 



fivepencetotal = input(("How many 5 Pence coins do you have? : ")) * fivepence

tenpencetotal = input(("How many 10 Pence coins do you have? : ")) * tenpence

twentypencetotal = input(("How many 20 Pence coins do you have? : ")) * twentypence

fiftypencetotal = input(("How many 50 pence coins do you have? : ")) * fiftypence

onepoundtotal = input(("How many 1 Pound coins do you have? : ")) * onepound

twopoundtotal = input(("How many 2 pound coins do you have? : ")) * twopound


#function to add everything and do the opposite if that is what the user wants

def changeaddup():
    print("do you want to add everything up?")
    print("Type either Yes, yes , Y or y to add all your change up")
    if input( "Yes","yes","Y","y"):
        print("Just calculating how much money you have based on the data you have inputed")
        print("Here you have a total of £", fivepencetotal + tenpencetotal + twentypencetotal + fiftypencetotal + onepoundtotal + twopoundtotal)
        
    else:
        return
print(changeaddup)
```

Comment: what do you mean by go through the process? what is your question exactly?

Comment: I hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908027/how-to-read-more-than-one-line-in-an-input-in-python/61908111#61908111

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my bad, i see what you mean by turning the input into a list, i want to have the user be able to input multiple bits of information such as "yes" "Yes" "y" "Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont exactly know what you want, but may be something like this

```
positive_choice_options = ["Yes","yes","Y","y"]

# and there can be other choice if you need. ie.
negetive_choice_options = ["No", "no", "N", "n"]

def normalized_user_choice(user_choice):
    if user_choice in positive_choice_options:
        return "yes"
    if user_choice in negetive_choice_options:
        return "no"

def changeaddup():
    print("do you want to add everything up?")
    user_choice = input("Type either Yes, yes , Y or y to add all your change up: ")
    if normalized_user_choice(user_choice)=="yes":
        print("Just calculating how much money you have based on the data you have inputed")
        print("Here you have a total of £", fivepencetotal + tenpencetotal + twentypencetotal + fiftypencetotal + onepoundtotal + twopoundtotal)
    else:
        return
```

Comment: That actually answered everything thank you i understand now with the creation of the arrays to make it so there is multiple choice for user input thank you.