# How to ignore the enter key/ treat it as the space key in Python?

Tags: python

So I want the user to enter a matrix in the form, for example:

```
 2 2
 3 4
```

I need Python to ignore the enter key here and treat it the same as the space bar, otherwise it would give me an error when I press the enter key after last number in the first row, making it only possible to enter the matrix as:

```
2 2 3 4
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just call `input` twice to get the two lines?

Comment: Because this is all stored in the same 2D array

Comment: So call `input` twice and store the results into a 2D array.

Comment: What data type is your matrix? In my answer I assumed you're talking about a nested list, but it just occurred to me that you might be using NumPy or something.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nested list

Comment: Is the input  always a square matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to input multiple lines, you can't just ignore a newline; instead you'll have to take multiple lines of input. See [How do I read multiple lines of raw input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11664443/4518341)

For example, based on [jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219006/jamylak)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664675/4518341):

```
matrix = []
for line in iter(input, ''):
    matrix.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

for x in matrix:
    print(x)
```

Input (note the blank line at the end):

```
2 3
3 4
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
```