# Python input gets cut off at first bracket

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have following input:

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "exchange": "NASDAQ",
  "exchangeSuffix": null,
  "exchangeDescription": "Nasdaq All Markets",
  "name": "Apple Inc"
}
```

When I paste it and print it, I get only `{` printed.
Since `raw_input` is now `input` in Python 3.x, I tried to use
`from six.moves import input` but it didn't help. So the input is somehow cut off.

My final goal is to remove

```
  "exchange": "NASDAQ",
  "exchangeSuffix": null,
  "exchangeDescription": "Nasdaq All Markets"
```

and print the rest.

Comment: If you're pasting that into the terminal, the new line after `{` is interpreted, like hitting Enter, as the end of the input. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11664443/3001761, you'll need to loop until what _you_ consider to be the end. Or read from a file, remove the newlines _before_ pasting, ...

Comment: If you NEED to enter it as input then you have to enter it as a single line.  I am assuming though this is output from an API which you could read directly from your script rather than entering as input

Comment: How do I enter it as a single line? It's available via API. What I try to use as input is a search result which is offered in a free version.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of importing input it is already imported in the file.I am not able to understand ur question properly

Comment: it's not a file. It is only in clipboard as it is info from a website. Any idea how to solve that problem?