# Entering multipleline input in python

Tags: python, input

How can i enter multiple lines input in python. I have tried input() function but it doesn't work properly. I would like to enter input like this:
3\n
12\n
504\n
17
(first line shows number of lines)

Comment: You can use multiple calls to `input`: each `input` will read one line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read multiple lines of raw input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely need to call the input() function multiple times to get the result you're wanting.

See this post for more information
[How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).