# How do I make multiline inputs using python?

Tags: python, replit

I am just learning python and have almost no experience and I have hit a bit of a problem. I am learning to edit text files and I am trying to see if I can copy multi-line text into the input() function when you run it, or if you can't do that. Also I am using Replit, if that's important.

Here is my code:

```
example = input("Some multi-line text: ")
print(example)
```

I have also tried using:

```
example = input("""Some multi-line text: """)
print(example)
```

but it didn't work either.

Then I tried typing `\n` into shell (remember I am using Replit).
That also didn't work, it just printed: example \n example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read multiple lines of raw input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-to-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input)

Comment: if you allow newline characters in your text how does input know that you have finished inputting text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the following Python snippet for multi-line processing.

```
delimiter = ''
for line in iter(input, delimiter):
    <do something here>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can code it so that there's a while loop taking the input constantly while adding to `user_text` with a new line at the end. You have a condition checking for a certain keyword to stop the loop.

```
user_text = ""
while True:
    new_text = input()
    if new_text == "end":
        break
    user_text += f"{new_text}\n"

print(user_text)
```