# Execute multiline code with tabs from input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```py
code = input()
eval(code)
```

If I run it and type
`> print(10)`
It will get executed and print "10"

My question is when the code needs an indent, such as:

```
> for i in range(10):
>    print(i)
```

How can I receive this code with `input()` (notice that I have to keep the indent) so that I can use `eval()` to run it?

Comment: Why not save it as code in a `.py` file ? What is your use case?

Comment: receive `input()` from the user and run it

Comment: Use `exec`, not `eval`, to execute a block of code stored as a string.

Comment: The question is how to save it as text in the first place

Comment: You should show us the code you're currently using to take input from the user so that we can see what difficulties you're running into in trying to preserve indentation.

Comment: Suppose I want to receive from the user a code of a loop to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to be able to get python code using `input()` with tabs included.

the post
[How to read multiple lines of raw input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11664443/8915326) tells us that we can get multiline input with

```py
code = '\n'.join(iter(input, ''))
```

But after trying that myself I noticed that `exec(code)` didn't work because tabs were omitted from the input.

So here's a function that reads character directly and stops when it reads a given string
(here it's 2 newlines so you have to press ENTER twice to stop)

```py
import sys

def input_until(sentinel):
    text = ""
    while not text.endswith(sentinel):
        text += sys.stdin.read(1)  # read 1 character from stdin
    # remove the stop string from the result
    return text[:-len(sentinel)]

code = input_until("\n\n")
exec(code)
```

I've tested it on https://replit.com/languages/python3 and it seems to work !

Answer (score -2):

What's your use case here?

If you want to run the string in `eval()`, do you consider this?

```py
new_string_name = "for i in range(10):\n    eval(a)"
```

or

```py
new_string_name = "    eval()"
```

But if you don't want to follow the indentation rules (4 characters, no tabs), you can use

```py
new_string_name = "for i in range(10):\n\teval(a)"
```

or

```py
new_string_name = "\teval(a)"
```

Comment: this Does not work