# How to add a new line to the string that I input to Python input()?

Tags: python

I ask user for some input using

```
s = input('enter something: ')
```

Then I save it to a text file.
I want my user to be able to input new lines using '\n'.

For example, if user input "hello\nbye", and I use `file.write(s)` to save the text, I want my text file to be:

```
hello
bye
```

But just typing in '\n' does not seen to work.
Specifying a replacement character then using `str.replace` is not an option for me.
I am using Python 3.11 but I can switch to any Python 3 version.

EDIT: I am interacting with the user through socket, and I cannot use sys.stdin.read() due to limitations with the console. I also cannot use the iter based solution as I only want the user to input once. Therefore, [How to read multiple lines of raw input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/how-to-read-multiple-lines-of-raw-input) does not resolve my issue.

Comment: How do you want the user input to end?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel by pressing enter on their console

Answer (score 0):

Since python's `input` can't turn `\n` into newline characters, you may need to do the conversion yourself:

```py
s = input('enter something: ') #e.g "hello\nworld"
s = s.replace('\\n', '\n') # turns literal '\n' text into newline characters
...
file.write(s)
```

Now, `s` will have newlines instead of `\n` and will write and print as expected.

Comment: I know this but as I said in the question, str.replace is not an option for me. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I missed that requirement - input doesn't seem to have any built-in ways of interpreting escape codes.