# Understanding input in iter

Tags: python

I was looking for solutions to take multiline input in python. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664675/16891669) answer which uses the following code.

```py
sentinel = '' # ends when this string is seen
for line in iter(input, sentinel):
    pass # do things here
```

I read from the python docs that if `iter` recieves the second argument then it will call the `__next__()` of the first argument. But I don't think `input` has the `__next__()` implemented (I am not able to verify this either through the docs or surfing through the source code). Can someone explain how it's working?

Also, I observed this weird behaviour with the following code.

```
sentinel = ''
itr = iter(input, sentinel)
print("Hello")
print(set(itr))
```

Here is the output

```
[dvsingla Documents]$ python3 temp.py
Hello
lksfjal
falkja
 aldfj

{' aldfj', 'falkja', 'lksfjal'}
[dvsingla Documents]$
```

The prompt starts taking input after printing *Hello* which is not following line by line interpretation.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe the `input` in that code is not the built-in `input` function. Instead, someone chose an unfortunate name for a local variables, as in `input = "abcd"`.

Comment: Did you try reading the docs for [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)?

Comment: @zvone. No, that's the input function all right

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh, that is even worse then :D Really ugly code in my opinion.

Comment: @zvone. Why? I think it's fine if you understand what it does

Comment: Your code is behaving exactly as the documentation says it will. The reference in the docs to \_\_next__ means *iter*'s \_\_next__ method and not the callable given as the first argument

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh well, it is just not explicit enough. Having a delayed/lazy evaluation of user interaction like that, using an iterator, just makes the code more difficult to understand. There is hardly ever a benefit which would justify it.

Comment: @zvone. It looks pretty clear if you know what the functions do. Admittedly the two-arg form of `iter` is a bit arcane, but it is clearly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) has three forms: two one-arg and a two-arg version. The first one-arg version is the one that you are likely more familiar with.

1. If `object` supports `__iter__`, `iter` will call that and return the result.
2. If not, `iter` will look for `__getitem__` (which is assumed to accept integers at that point) and `__len__`. If both are found in `object`, `iter` will instantiate its own internal iterator type that has a `__next__` method which increments the index to `object.__getitem__` calls until it reaches `__len__`.
3. The two-arg form is much less used (and probably less known). It takes two arguments: `object` is a no-arg callable, and `sentinel` is a value that will be compared to what `object` returns to determine the end of iteration. In this case `iter` returns an instance of an internal class which supports `__next__`, just like for #2. Each call to `__next__` will delegate to `object` until it returns `sentinel`. That's the version that you see being used here.

In all three cases, `object` itself does not need to implement `__next__` directly. The iterator returned by `iter` does. For case #1, that's something `object` produces. For cases #2 and #3, is a wrapper made by `iter`.

The reason that the printouts happen as they do is that all forms of `iter` return a lazy iterator, not just the first form. `itr` will not execute anything until the call to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#set), which will repeatedly call [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) through `itr.__next__()`. This will continue until the user enters an empty line, which will be equal to the chosen `sentinel`.

Comment: To get the next value, isn't it compulsory for `__next__()` to be implemented? The doc says , `If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its __next__() method`.

Comment: Should an object have explicit `__next__()` method or are there other ways as well?

Comment: @Dhruv. The docs are saying that the iterator which is returned from that call to `iter` will have a `__next__` method, not the object you passed in. Each call to that `__next__` method will call the function you passed in as the first argument until it returns the sentinel value. It's important to read carefully.

Comment: Could you add the above in the answer as this was the main part of my question. I got confused regarding `__next__` due to to some examples on the internet.

Comment: @Dhruv. How's it look now?

Comment: @Dhruv. I didn't like the edits you made, but hopefully the update clarifies the parts you were having a problem with